# Making the app recognize "the right answer"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3

I am new in the game, so probably an easy issue. What I am trying to do is to make an app with a question asked, and a textFiled in which to answer. Then, i want the app to recognize when the answer is right (in this case the number 25) and when it is wrong (not 25). Everything is working fine, and I get the "wrong" message, but I cant make it recognize the right answer.

```
- (IBAction)btnSubmitAction:(id)sender {
if (textFieldAnswer.text == @"25") {
    lblAnswer.text = @"Yes, your right!";
    btnNext.hidden = 0;
} else {
    lblAnswer.text = @"No, try again.";
}
```

}

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's "Yes, you're right!"  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is how you're supposed to compare strings:

```
- (IBAction)btnSubmitAction:(id)sender {
if ([textFieldAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"25"]) {
    lblAnswer.text = @"Yes, you're right!";
    btnNext.hidden = NO;
} else {
    lblAnswer.text = @"No, try again.";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing objects in Objective-C is done by ==. This means that you compare pointers, which is not the same as comparing strings, because they are pointers. If you would like to compare strings for equality you should call the `BOOL` instance method `isEqualToString` of `NSString` class.

```
[string1 isEqualToString:@"someString"]
```